# R - rolling 12 month median by group with inconsistent time interval

Tags: r, group-by, moving-average

I have data (values) collected over several years by numerous groups. I would like to calculate the 12 month rolling median (using the 12 previous months) for each group. I've looked into the zoo (and other) roll functions and they seem to all be fixed interval (eg 12 months = 12 rows), but the date intervals in my data are not consistent for each group. Data values were collected every month or every other month, but there are additional gaps as well. I guess I need a rolling median function that gathers values for the previous 364 days for each group. I'd appreciate some help!

Below is an example of my data:

```
Date    Group   Value
8/17/2013   A   5
10/2/2013   A   13
1/15/2014   A   11
3/15/2014   A   2
5/22/2014   A   7
7/15/2014   A   1
9/3/2014    A   1
11/15/2014  A   7
7/22/2013   B   13
8/5/2013    B   13
9/7/2013    B   12
10/16/2013  B   6
11/17/2013  B   5
12/9/2013   B   15
1/30/2014   B   1
2/23/2014   B   10
3/24/2014   B   15
4/5/2014    B   3
5/26/2014   B   3
6/16/2014   B   4
8/5/2014    B   6
9/26/2014   B   8
10/16/2014  B   15
11/29/2014  B   12
12/13/2016  B   1
```

I want to add a column to this table "Rolling Median" that contains the rolling 12 month (or 365 day) median for each group.

Comment: Could you please add a desired output (at least few rows)?

Comment: This is not so.  `rollapply` can use a possibly different width for each function application; however, it is then up to you to specify them.

Comment: I have more than five hundred different groups, so specifying a different width for each isn't a feasible option.

Comment: output required would be for Group A as follows: 7/15/2014 median = 6, 9/3/2014 median = 4.5, 11/15/2014 median = 4.5

Answer (score 3):

This package might be helpful to you:

https://github.com/mgahan/boRingTrees

It is called `boRingTrees` and it handles this type of problem. If you don't want to download the package, you can use the following code as well:

```
##Utilize the data.table package
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, Date2 := as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")] #Format date field

#Apply rollingByCalcs function (full function code is below)
data[, Roll_Median := rollingByCalcs(data,bylist=c("Group"),dates="Date2",target="Value",
                      lower=0,upper=365,incbounds=T,stat=median,na.rm=T,cores=1)]


rollingByCalcs <- function(data,bylist=NULL,dates,target=NULL,
                           lower,upper,incbounds=T,stat=length,na.rm=T,cores=1){
  tic <- Sys.time()

  require("data.table")
  require("parallel")
  data <- data.table(data)


  if (is.null(bylist)){
    data[, id.filler := 1]
    bylist <- "id.filler"
  }

  if (is.null(target)){
    data[,target:=1]
    target <- "target"
  }

  ##Create group by variable
  data[,Grp.Var:=.GRP,by=bylist]

  ##Assign variable names
  data[,target:=data[,eval(parse(text=target))]]
  data[,dates:=data[,eval(parse(text=dates))]]

  ##Create "list" of comparison dates
  Ref <- data[,list(Compare_Value=list(I(target)),Compare_Date=list(I(dates))), by=c("Grp.Var")]

  ##Compare two lists and see of the compare date is within N days
  data$Roll.Val <- mcmapply(FUN = function(RD, NUM) {
    d <- as.numeric(RD-Ref$Compare_Date[[NUM]])
    true.vals <- between(x=d,lower=lower,upper=upper,incbounds=incbounds)  
    out <- stat(Ref$Compare_Value[[NUM]][true.vals])
    return(out)
  }, RD = data$dates,NUM=data$Grp.Var,mc.cores=cores)

  print(Sys.time()-tic)
  return(data$Roll.Val)
}
```

Comment: Mike, This looks like ti could help, but I can't get this to install. I am running R v 3.2.1.

Comment: What OS platform are you on? `Mac`, `Linux`, `Windows`? I think Windows needs the `RTools` packages. I think `Mac` and `Linux` need the `devtools` packages.

Comment: `library("devtools");`
`install_github("boRingTrees","mgahan")`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper function.  Here's one using the [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
library(dplyr)
rollingMedian <- function(targetDate, targetGroup) {
  dat %>%
    mutate(thisDiff = difftime(as.Date(Date), targetDate, unit = "days")) %>%
    filter(thisDiff < 0, thisDiff > -366, Group == targetGroup) %>%
    summarise(medValue = median(Value))
}

dat$rollingMed <- mapply(rollingMedian, dat$Date, dat$Group)
```

**Result:**

```
dat
         Date Group Value rollingMed
1  2013-08-17     A     5         NA
2  2013-10-02     A    13          5
3  2014-01-15     A    11          9
4  2014-03-15     A     2         11
5  2014-05-22     A     7          8
6  2014-07-15     A     1          7
7  2014-09-03     A     1          7
8  2014-11-15     A     7          2
9  2013-07-22     B    13         NA
10 2013-08-05     B    13         13
...
```

**Data used:**

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1376697600, 1380672000, 1389744000, 
1394841600, 1400716800, 1405382400, 1409702400, 1416009600, 1374451200, 
1375660800, 1378512000, 1381881600, 1384646400, 1386547200, 1391040000, 
1393113600, 1395619200, 1396656000, 1401062400, 1402876800, 1407196800, 
1411689600, 1413417600, 1417219200, 1481587200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), Value = c(5L, 13L, 11L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 5L, 15L, 1L, 10L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
8L, 15L, 12L, 1L)), .Names = c("Date", "Group", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam. However, when I run the function, I get the same value repeated throughout the entire table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you calling it using an `apply()` function?  And is your goal to have a new column with the rolling median for the group + date specified in each row?  BTW I missed the note about the rolling medians being group-specific and I've updated my code accordingly.  Now the function is called with `mapply()` but if anyone has a suggestion for calling the function within a dplyr pipeline I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Sam, Thanks for the updated code. Now I get an error that I've never encountered before: zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: when you call `mapply(...)` do the argument names match those in your data.frame?  I think one of the `mapply()` arguments is not being passed correctly.  For instance replace my last line above with `dat$rollingMed <- mapply(rollingMedian, dat$Date, dat$causeError)` and it produces that message.